# In Dash (python), I have problem with slider and radioitem callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, dashboard

Upon callback I get two errors:

1. Property "slidevalue" was used with component ID:
   "ageslider" in one of the Input items of a callback.
   **This ID is assigned to a dash_core_components.RangeSlider component in the layout, which does not support this property**.
2. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

My code is:

```
dbc.Col([
                html.Div(id='Title_Slider', children='''Milo na ena LOLA''',
                         style={'margin-bottom':'50px', 'text-align':'center'}),
                html.Div(dcc.RangeSlider(id='**ageslider**',min=18,max=60,step=1,value=[18,60],
                        marks={str(Age): str(Age) for Age in data.Age.unique()}
                ), style={'width': '100%', 'padding': '0px 20px 20px 20px'}),
```

and

```
@app.callback(
    Output('bar-1', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown1','value'),
    Input('ageslider','slidevalue'),
    Input('binat','bivalue'))    
def update_line_chart(filter_metric, **vage** , bi_value):
    v_min = **vage**[0]
    v_max = **vage**[1]
#age_filter is a custom func that works
    datac_ = age_filter(data, v_min, v_max)
    a=datac_.groupby([filter_metric,'Attrition']).apply(lambda x:x[filter_metric].count()).reset_index(name='Counts')
    fig = px.line(a, x=filter_metric, y="Counts", color='Attrition',markers=True,height=500, width=700)
    fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor=colors['background'],paper_bgcolor=colors['background'], font_color=colors['text'])
    return fig
```

Does anyone know why RangeSlider faces this issue??

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

Comment: are you sure it should be `slidevalue`? As for me it should be `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `value` instead of `slidevalue`

```
Input('ageslider','value'),
```

I can't test second problem but I think `value` should also resolve it.

---

Minimal working example:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Age': list(range(18, 61, 5))
})    

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dbc.Col([
    html.Div(id='Title_Slider', children='''Milo na ena LOLA'''),
    dcc.RangeSlider(id='ageslider', min=18, max=60, step=1, value=[18,60],
        marks={str(Age): str(Age) for Age in data.Age.unique()}
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown1',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
                        {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
                        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
                    ],
                    value='NYC'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='bar-1'),    
    html.Div(id='output-text'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('bar-1', 'figure'),
    Output('output-text', 'children'),
    Input('dropdown1','value'),
    Input('ageslider','value'),
    #Input('binat','value')
)    
def update_line_chart(dropdown_value, slide_value): #, bi_value):
    print('min_val:', slide_value[0])
    print('max_val:', slide_value[1])
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=[1, 2], y=slide_value)])
    text = f"{dropdown_value}: min: {slide_value[0]}, max: {slide_value[1]}"
    return fig, text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]